# Is there anyway to set the window position for TERM WXT?

Tags: cygwin, gnuplot

There is no SET TERM POSITION option in gnuplot.

I am using cygwin on windows 7.

Is there some kind of work-around?

Comment: Do you mean the position on the overall screen of the computer where the gnuplot graph pops up when you plot something?

Answer (score 4):

Gnuplot version 5.0 knows a `position` option for the interactive terminals:

```
set terminal wxt 0 position 0,0
plot x

set terminal wxt 1 position 200,200
plot x**2
```